# How to generate new random circles based on distance from head circle in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, random, html5-canvas, geometry, computational-geometry

I have drawn a circle on a random position within a range on a canvas in JavaScript.

I want to generate 2 more circles on a random position on a specific distance (200) from the center of the 1st circle.

There is a way to generate new coordinates until the distance is equal to 200, but there should be a better solution, right?

How can I do the following?

[image]

**Code:**

```
var x = getRandomInt(200, 800)
var y = getRandomInt(200, 400)
var r = 60
drawCircle (x, y, r)

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
}

function drawCircle(x, y, r) {  
    context.beginPath()
    context.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)
    context.fillStyle = "#fc3358"
    context.fill()
    context.closePath()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate point at random angle with distance R (here 200) from central point (CX, CY), use simple trigonometry formula:

```
Phi = Random * 2 * Math.PI; //Random in range 0..1
X = CX + Round(R * Cos(Phi));
Y = CY + Round(R * Sin(Phi));
```

Comment: Awesome! This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pythagorean theorem to find out all points that are 200 distance from an other. You are basically looking for a circle that has a radius of 200. So in the end you will get a function, you plug that puppy in and assign it the random value. Have a look at the distance formula, it might clear the concept up.

Comment: Do the math, come back with it so I can further assist you :).

Comment: But for this method I still need to loop and check if a coordinate's distance is equal to 200, right? Is there no better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pythagorean theorem as noted by Gabriel above. If you do not want to calculate all points, you can assign one set of numbers to be random, then you can manipulate the theorm to calculate the second number: b = Sqrt(c^2 - a^2)